# mysql BETWEEN will return 0 rows

Tags: php, mysql, between

I have a MySQL table with price structure something like this:

```
-------------------- 
| Price | item_id  |
--------------------
|$10,999|  123     |
|$5,889 |  321     |
|$2999  |  143     | 
|------------------|
```

Now if i Query this :

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE price BETWEEN "$2999" AND "$6000";
```

It will return two rows. But if i Query this :

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE price BETWEEN "$2999" AND "$20000";
```

It won't return any row as it is expected to return atleast 3 rows?

Please note that there are many other rows aswell which are $11,000, and so on...

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be storing it as string or varchar. The way it performs now is it compares for string that's why you have not result. If I were you, I will restructure the table by altering column `Price` to be `INT` or `DECIMAL`, or whatever as long as it is a number.

But to answer your question directly, you can do this but doesn't use any index if you have define one.

```
WHERE CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(price,'$',''),',','') AS SIGNED) 
      BETWEEN 2999 AND 20000
```

Comment: this worked great! up voted, but can you explain if it impacts the performance of the page?

Comment: @Ahsan you must convert the column to a decimal type and add an index to it, since you will run many queries using this column in order to have the best performance.

Comment: Thank you, did accordingly, got the best!

Answer (score 2):

It would seem that you are storing the price as a string rather than a number.  There is nothing between "$2999" and "$20000" because "$2999" > "$20000" alphabetically.

Here is one way to fix this:

```
SELECT 
FROM products
WHERE cast(replace(replace(price, '$', ''), ',') as signed) BETWEEN 2999 AND 20000;
```

A better way would be to store the "price" as a number rather than a character.

Comment: in `mysql`, you should use `SIGNED` or `UNSIGNED` otherwise it will throw an error.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that Price is a text field and not a numeric one. So, when you try to fetch rows between $2999 and $20000 nothing is returned, because actually 20000 is smaller than 2999 when compared as strings.

You must convert the column to a decimal data type with two decimal points.

Comment: you mean comparing 20000 and 2999 , 20000 is smaller? like 20000 < 2999?

Comment: Yes, when you compare them as strings.

Answer (score 1):

Drop the `$` and leave numbers only. You do not need to save dollar sign with numbers in DB.

`SELECT * FROM products WHERE price > 2999 AND price < 6000;`

`SELECT * FROM products WHERE price > 2999 AND price < 20000;`

or

`SELECT * FROM products WHERE price BETWEEN 2999 AND 6000";`

`SELECT * FROM products WHERE price BETWEEN 2999 AND 20000";`

Comment: this would still return 0 rows? But i have used CAST(replace(replace..)); and it worked, but the performance and response was indeed slow.